# How to get accessToken from AWS Cognito when using Ionic's (cordova) Facebook Plugin?

Tags: facebook, authentication, ionic-framework, amazon-cognito

I need to exchange facebook's accessToken with Cognito accessToken. I am getting the session Token but dont know how to get the access token.

I need to use the Ionic' native facebook plugin to sign-in to AWS Conito user pool.

I have setup the Cognito user pool and the federation identity providers as required. I have also setup a identity pool for this purpose. Here are steps that I followed ...

1) I am using Ionic's facebook plugin to sign-in and am getting the access token from facebook
2) Sending this access token to Cognito with the below code snippet
3) As response from Cognito (amazon-cognito-identity-js) I am getting the session token. I need the access token instead.

-> Login with facebook 
import { Facebook, FacebooginResponse } from "@ionic-native/facebook";

```
this.fb
  .login(["public_profile", "email"])
  .then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
    console.log("Logged into Facebook!", res);
  }
```

-> I am getting the access token from facebook
-> Now passing it to Cognito

```
AWS.config.region = "ap-south-1"; // Region
let params = {
  IdentityPoolId: "ap-south-1:<xxxxxxxx>",
  Logins: {
    "graph.facebook.com": authResult.accessToken
  }
};
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(params);

(<AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials> AWS.config.credentials).get((err) => {
  if (err) console.log(err.stack);
  else 
    console.log("AWS Credentials:", AWS.config.credentials);
```

-> Here I am getting session token. I need the access token instead.

What I need is the Cognito Access token to proceed further with our API. Please help.

Comment: Did you figure it out?